# simple_fields_for doesn't generate input when value for column is nil

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, web, simple-form-for

I'm trying to load post with no comments, but this form is not shown:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :comments  do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.input :COMM_TEXT, as: :text%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

How to make it visible if no comments yet for post to add them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make it visible if no comments yet for post to add them.

I suggest you to create a new comment, it's not persist in database, it's just a template for new comment:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@task) do |f| %>
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :comments, @task.comments.new  do |comment| %>
    <%= comment.input :COMM_TEXT, as: :text%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

<sub>Here is a good article about nested forms [which I recommend to read](https://coderwall.com/p/qwx3qa/nested-form-and-rails-4).</sub>

Comment: now I got error:  unknown attribute 'task_id' for Comment.

Comment: This error say that your Comment model not related to the Task model. [Read the basic about assosations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'comm'
  belongs_to :task
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'task'
  has_many :comments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments
end

Comment: @si13n it say nothing for me.

Comment: You can also use `f.simple_fields_for Comment.new` instead of `@task.comments.new`.

Comment: Yeah that's works, but it not resolve a problem, your Task not related to Comment, what's mean you can't fetch all comment of the task.

Comment: i have belongs_to and has_many assosiations in my Models.. but still have this problem..

Comment: I strongly recommend you to read the basic about associations from the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Just declare a belongs_to\has_many does nothing for associations on the database. You should add a `task_id` to the Comment table.